# Convert a binary file to multiple graphic images using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, binaryfiles, graphic, file-conversion

I have a **64 bit unsigned binary file** that contains multiple images, this file is an output of a numeric analysis software that is designed to store **graphic information in binary form**. The software itself has its builtin function to export images but it's an old software, doing that is an pain in the ass.

So I am trying to convert this file to multiple images using python. I found an potential solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246316/displaying-data-from-binary-file-in-python).

The following is the code I copied from aforementioned post with minimal change for my specific file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    data = read_data('test21.SGR', 8192, 8192)
    visualize(data)

def read_data(filename, width, height):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        # Skip the header
        infile.seek(8192)
        data = np.fromfile(infile, dtype=np.uint64)
    # Reshape the data into a 3D array. (-1 is a placeholder for however many
    # images are in the file... E.g. 2000)
    return data.reshape((width, height, -1))

def visualize(data):
    # There are better ways to do this, but let's keep it simple
    plt.ion()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(data[:,:,0], cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    for i in xrange(data.shape[-1]):
        image = data[:,:,i]
        im.set(data=image, clim=[image.min(), image.max()])
        fig.canvas.draw()

main()
```

But when I use this code the error says:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

If this will work out I will be basically saving at least 2 hours at work from image extraction. I am a newbie in Python so I don't quite understand how to resolve this issue, any help will be appreciated here.

Comment: in `read_data` what is `data.shape`? It looks like your error is at that reshape, so I'd guess that `width, height` is different from `data.shape`

Comment: I think the error is at the reshape function too, even if I only ran the first two functions, the same error exists.

Comment: have you inserted a `print data.shape` to see what it gives you (and comment out the return statement for now)

Comment: I just did and it gives me `(21275752L,)`, 21275752 is the output of len(data) as well

Comment: You've got a 1D array, that's just over 4512 squared. For a single image that is 8192 x 8192, you'd need an array of 67108864, that's why reshape is failing. Are you sure the `seek(8192)` is doing what you intended?

Comment: honestly I am not sure, I think if the data is 64 bit I can't get an array of  67108864

Comment: Could your images be smaller than 8192? How many images do you have?

Comment: The binary file itself is 162 MB, it has tons of images. The way I came up with 8192 is the same as the original post, with 64 bit 64*64*2 = 8192.

Comment: The original problem was 512 * 512 bytes, your calculation is using 64 *64 bits in the same calculation

Comment: you are right, I messed up on that part. Should be 8*8*2 = 128. But it still give me the same error.

Comment: seems like your seek must be going to the wrong place

Comment: Also, I just found out the file I'm trying to convert is not purely 64bit data string, it has readable content in it when I open it in notepad. Arrrg, I guess I'll stick with the old method. Thanks a bunch for helping me tho.

Comment: It sounds like your file has a lot of similarities with the .fcs file standard, for which there are python packages available. If you can get a really good handle on your file structure, you would definitely be able to do something with this. It's not something I've ever got too far into though. It's a really interesting problem though

Comment: Yep, it is indeed a interesting problem. Being an engineer does not have all the time to investigate this kind of problem though :(. I also discovered that Integrated Genome Browser uses .sgr file, I am completely oblivious to how to use that software.

Comment: I know the feeling. If you ever feel like tackling it informally, feel free to get in touch, I'd be interested on lending a hand.

Comment: @Andrew,I would love to get help from you, I am not sure what do you mean by "tackling it informally" I just want to know how to get this solved, that's what matters for me. Let me know if you are still interested !

Comment: I just mean in my spare time... There doesn't seem to be any messaging function on this site though to exchange contact details, etc.

Comment: Understood, I can share with you the .sgr file on my googledrive and you can fiddle with it when you feel like doing it, if you don't mind.

Comment: That sounds good, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrew !     https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4T5VVuWv73EQU9tXzRzV2FoTUE

Comment: Got it, Thanks. Looking at it now

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks for the help :)